# Compile time check if file at path exists? like include_str!(..)

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I like how `include_str!(..)` works. Is there a macro that simply checks if the file exists instead of loading the contents of the file?

Use case? I want to make sure that all the file paths that are valid before I release it, to prevent runtime error.

So the file path has to be checked even if the macro isn't called during runtime.

OR should I be using tests here?

Comment: you could implement your own - you can even see how `include_str!` is implemented

Comment: @DanielA.White I looked for the implementation of``include_str!`` but it is compiler built-in, so I'm not quite sure how it's implemented

Comment: @DanielA.White include_str is built-in. Are you recommending he write another compiler built-in and make a new compiler? Seems like overkill.

Comment: You could do this with a proc macro; [see here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/opening-files-in-proc-macros/11387) for how to find the path to the project directory, and from that point you could just use the `std::fs` API to check that the files exist.

Comment: Just wondering is it applicable in your case to check that from cargo build file?

Comment: @SudipGhimire I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Put the code to check if file exists just like you do in rutime but in `build.rs` file so It will execute in compile time and not be included in runtime binary. ref: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html

Comment: @SudipGhimire that sounds like an option, but not very straightforward in my case. Thanks

Comment: What's not straightforward about adding `assert!(Path::new("path").exists());` to your `build.rs`?

Comment: @PitaJ Well, won't I have to do that for each of the hundreds of paths? I just want to make sure that each and every call that uses a certain path in the code is guaranteed to be available, with no chance of human error.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to do the same with a macro like `include_str!`?

Comment: @PitaJ I am using the paths in my code. So I would have to use them in my code and also put each of the paths inside build.rs to verify them. Double the work, no? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I see, you want code locality. Why not create a macro that uses `let _ = include_bytes!(path)` and then returns the path?

Comment: @PitaJ I also thought of that, it's the most straightforward method! But it does come with a performance hit, I think (have not measured). So I'm trying to create a procedural macro, which would do exactly what I want and nothing more and measure the performance difference afterwards.

Comment: A performance difference at compile time or at runtime?

Comment: @PitaJ compile time of course. My rust compilations already take so much time lol.

Comment: Introducing a proc macro, especially where you aren't already using one, is likely to affect your compile times more. You may wish to reference how [`include_optional` does it](https://github.com/eliasholzmann/include_optional)

Comment: @PitaJ you know what, I am having difficulty implementing a proc macro. So I'll give it a try.
I'll implement the proc macro another time to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do for now.

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! find_file{
    ($arg1:literal) => {
        {
            //opportunity for improvement
            let _ = include_bytes!($arg1);
            let r = $arg1;
            r
        }
    };
}
```

@PitaJ thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand the source code of include_optional: [github](https://github.com/EliasHolzmann/include_optional/blob/master/src/lib.rs). So I don't want to use it